# "Existing subscription to channel" while only subscribing once

Tags: javascript, pusher

I have a small snippet that throws an "Existing subscription to channel" exception even though I only call the subscribe method once.

This can be avoided by moving the subscribe request outside of the "state_change" handler, but I'm wondering what might cause this? Maybe a bug in the Pusher library?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Pusher subscribe testcase</h1>
    <p>Tip: check your console</p>
    <script src="https://d3dy5gmtp8yhk7.cloudfront.net/2.1/pusher.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var pusher, channel;
        pusher = new Pusher('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
        pusher.connection.bind('state_change', function(change){
            if(change.current === 'connected'){
                console.log('connected');
                channel = pusher.subscribe('test-channel');
                channel.bind('pusher:subscription_succeeded', function() {
                    console.log('subscribed');
                });
            }
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This results in:

```
connected
subscribed
Pusher : Error : {"type":"WebSocketError","error":{"type":"PusherError","data":{"code":null,"message":"Existing subscription to channel test-channel"}}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While it does look like a bug in the library (do report it!), you don't need to bind to the `state_change` event in order to subscribe to channels.

If you look at the code for the subscribe event in `pusher.js`:

```
prototype.subscribe = function(channel_name) {
  var self = this;
  var channel = this.channels.add(channel_name, this);

  if (this.connection.state === 'connected') {
    channel.authorize(this.connection.socket_id, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        channel.handleEvent('pusher:subscription_error', data);
      } else {
        self.send_event('pusher:subscribe', {
          channel: channel_name,
          auth: data.auth,
          channel_data: data.channel_data
        });
      }
    });
  }
  return channel;
};
```

you'll see that it will first add your channel to an internal list of channels via the `channels.add` method, which looks like this:

```
prototype.add = function(name, pusher) {
  if (!this.channels[name]) {
    this.channels[name] = createChannel(name, pusher);
  }
  return this.channels[name];
};
```

It will only add the channel in case you haven't previously subscribed.

So, if you were to subscribe to a channel *before* the connection is established, the Pusher client will only add the channel to the list. Once the client has established a connection, it will call the `subscribe` method again for every channel in its list via the `subscribeAll` method:

```
this.connection.bind('connected', function() {
  self.subscribeAll();
});
```

And seeing that at this point `this.connection.state` **is** `connected`, it will connect.

So, recapping, don't bother binding to the `state_change` event to subscribe, just subscribe, like so:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Pusher subscribe testcase</h1>
    <p>Tip: check your console</p>
    <script src="https://d3dy5gmtp8yhk7.cloudfront.net/2.1/pusher.js"></script>
    <script>
        var pusher, channel;

        pusher = new Pusher('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
        channel = pusher.subscribe('test-channel');
        channel.bind('pusher:subscription_succeeded', function() {
            console.log('subscribed');
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "you don't need to bind to the state_change event in order to subscribe to channels" - That's correct, but really only came across this behaviour by accident :)

Reposted this in Pusher's issue tracker https://github.com/pusher/pusher-js/issues/45

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a bug. If you open up the Network tab in dev tools and look at the WebSocket connection "Frames" information you can see the `pusher:subscribe` protocol event being sent twice. However, the code is definitely only calling `pusher.subscribe` once.

You should raise this bug with Pusher support or by submitting an issue to the [github repo](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-js/issues).

[image: pusher:subscribe protocol event sent twice]