# Pusher "existing subscription to channel" error

Tags: angularjs, pusher

I am getting the following error from pusher:

```
Pusher : Error : {"type":"WebSocketError","error":    
{"type":"PusherError","data":{"code":null,"message":"Existing subscription to 
channel room-1"}}}
```

I use angular. Every time I enter the "room" state, I set up pusher to subscribe to the room channel. However, if at some point I leave the room state and then come back, it tries to subscribe a second time and throws the above error. I tried to first check for an existing subscription using pusher.channel, but it doesn't seem to work. Anyone have any idea what's wrong? (my coffeescript code is below)

```
pusher = $pusher($window.client)

unless pusher.channel('room-' + $scope.room.id)
  room_channel = pusher.subscribe('room-' + $scope.room.id)
```

I should note that pusher.channel seems to work when I manually execute in the chrome console...

Comment: Are you directly using the Pusher JavaScript library or are you using [pusher-angular](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-angular/)?

Comment: I'm using pusher-angular :)

Comment: Would it please be possible to get a bit of debug info? 1. Output from [Pusher.log](https://pusher.com/docs/debugging#pusher_logging) 2. Some `console.log` around the `unless` check. Maybe output the value of `pusher.allChannels()` and the value of `'room-' + $scope.room.id`? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @David, I'm one of the people who worked on the library and this does sound like a bug. Do you have a small example app where the problem is occurring that I can take a look at? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've been getting the same issue over the last few days, using angular-pusher as well..

Answer (score 0):

I got the same behavior, and I found that I was putting the binding function both after a successful login and in my ui-router resolvers.
Check ["Existing subscription to channel" while only subscribing once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17833502/existing-subscription-to-channel-while-only-subscribing-once) for some hints - it looks like a bug in the original pusher.js library when connecting multiple times to the same channel while not yet connected to Pusher.